# Call .ashx handler from button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-applications, ashx

ashx handler to download some files when user clicks a button. My .aspx looks like this right now

```
<asp:Button OnClick:"Download" runat="server" />
```

And within the `Download` event I have to do some processing before the download starts. So I'm looking for a way to invoke the handler from my C# code and pass in some parameters that are required for the download process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't see any problems, in your c# code behind :

```
protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //retreiving page parameters
     string text = txtSomeTextBox.Text;
     int i = Convert.ToInt32(txtSomeOtherTextBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. But how do I pass these retrieved parameters to my handler? Do I have to use querystring?

Comment: if i'm not wrong, you are using asp.net web form, if it's the case, your ashx file have a c# code behind, wich should be called Name.ashx.cs, if it's not the case... this is useless

Comment: How about using the aspx code behind instead ? because i see ashx dosen't have front hand

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. using aspx code behind to invoke is what I'm working trying to do...

Comment: You are already able to reach the code behind of your aspx, now you want to call an event handler with parameters ? then show us the code of your atempt with comments to show where the missing code should be